# How to store enums in external file and import in java code

Tags: java, enums, enumeration, properties-file

How to store enum in separate file and import in java code. In the following code I have created enum for hostMessages. In that, it has more than 3000 errorcodes. So it is failing to compile. So I am trying to store it externally and call it while runtime.

The following code is working fine with less number of error codes. But for 3000 error codes it is failing to compile.

```
public class HostErrorMessages {

    public static enum HostMessages {
    
        ER_1001(1001, "MBM5269",
                "Errro code MBM5269"), ER_3045(3045,
                "AML01", "Transaction Failed");

        private Object errorCode;
        private String hostCode;
        private String errMsg;

        HostMessages(Object errorCode, String hostCode, String msg) {
            this.errorCode = errorCode;
            this.hostCode = hostCode;
            this.errMsg = msg;
        }
    }

    public static String getHostErrorMsgbyCode(String code) {
        String result = "";
        for (HostMessages em : HostMessages.values()) {
            if (em.hostCode.equalsIgnoreCase(code)) {
                result = em.errMsg;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I'd use an enum for this but rather a Java class, with objects created from the stored data.

Comment: Do you really think that there’s any worth in mapping an error code  “MBM5269” to an error message “Errro code MBM5269” or the code “AML01” to the message “Transaction Failed”? Then, you can implement the entire `getHostErrorMsgbyCode` method like `return "Something bad happened.";`

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be stored at DB level and get once and store it in Session with proper data structure like Map, HashTable.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are trying to model error codes with enums, and it is failing because you have so many error codes that Java cannot handle modeling them as an enum. In response to that problem, you are trying to de/serialize error codes into enums, but running into the exact same issue again.

Here is the simple fact -- Java has a limit of ~2.6k enum values ***THAT CONTAIN STATE*** before it goes pop. If you have more enum values ***THAT CONTAIN STATE*** than ~2.6k, then enums are not going to be a good solution. You need to do something else.

What you are trying to do is currently ***impossible in Java*** with enums.